# How do I make a horizontal histogram in Plotly express using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly, histogram

I'm trying to make a horizontal histogram with my data but I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

I always get a beautiful histogram when I use

```
px.histogram(df, x="columnName")
```

But the moment I try to change it to horizontal, it doesn't work.

```
px.histogram(df, y="columnName") or px.histogram(df, x="columnName", orientation='h') don't work.
```

I have no data with NoneType and I even tried `px.histogram(y=np.random.randn(500))` but it still doesn't work.

I tried using `go.Figure(data=[go.Histogram(y=df['columnName'])])` which does give me a horizontal hist but then I'm unable to change the colors according to a different column.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why is this tagged matplotlib if you are looking for a plotly solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Suggestion

If you take a look at the details below, you'll see that I fully agree that this is a little strange. But if you'd like to determine the orientation, just leave out the `orientation` parameter and switch between assigning the values to `x` and `y`.

#### Horizontal

```
fig = px.histogram(x=np.random.randn(500))
```

[image]

#### Vertical

```
fig = px.histogram(y=np.random.randn(500))
```

[image]

#### Details

This whole thing seems a bit strange. `orientation` is listed as a parameter for `px.histogram` and *should* take either `'h'` or `'v'` as valid arguments.

> orientation: str, one of `'h'` for horizontal or `'v'` for vertical.
> (default `'v'` if `x` and `y` are provided and both continuous or both
> categorical,  otherwise `'v'`(`'h'`) if `x`(`y`) is categorical and
> `y`(`x`) is continuous,  otherwise `'v'`(`'h'`) if only `x`(`y`) is

But I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

In any case, `px.histogram(x=np.random.randn(500))` produces the following horizontal plot plot:

[image]

If you'd like to flip it to vertical, just exchange `x with y`:

```
px.histogram(y=np.random.randn(500))
```

[image]